# Rails No Routes matching url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So my route is:

```
match '/user/:username/' => 'user/account/home#index', via: [ :get ], as: :user_view, constraints: UserConstraint
```

And the code of the controller is:

```
class User::Account::HomeController < User::ApplicationController
    def index
        @account = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    end
end
```

However when I call that url (ie; http://example.com/user/xerax), this is the error that rails throws at me:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"user/account/home", :username=>nil}
```

edit: I'm using Rails 3.2.13

Comment: What version of rails are you using

Comment: Updated my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine ([@readingr_uk](https://twitter.com/readingr_uk)), showed me how to fix this. I changed the routes from using :username to using :id

```
match '/user/:id/' => 'user/account/home#index', via: [ :get ], as: :user_view, constraints: UserConstraint
```